# Can't load image in stack in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart, stack

I want to load image in my app
in stack
but image not load
I don't have an error

I've add image in pubspec and pub it .

this is part of my code :

```
InkWell(
       

   child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Image.asset('assets/Images/b.jpg',fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                Center(child: Text("something",textAlign: TextAlign.center,)),
              ]
          ),
          onTap: () {
            ListOfEpisode();
            print("am");
          },
        ),
```

I've try it with network image but still not work.

anyone know that why i can't loaded ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: what happens when you run this?

Comment: share image in question

Comment: 1) show the directory structure where the image is stored
2) show your pubsec file

Comment: ok i've uploade it in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it towercase `i`:

```
new Image.asset('assets/images/b.jpg',fit: BoxFit.cover,),
```

In your pubespec you have it `assets/images`, in your code it's `Images`. Fix one of them.

Comment: your right thanks :) . how can i set Radius.circular for image ?

Comment: Of course you can, wrap it with a circle avatar, give it a max raduis of how much you want, and  use your Asset.image for background. Please mark this as the correct answer to your question, thanks!

Comment: i don't know how to do it in stack

Comment: Create a seperate post please, to keep every question relating to a single problem.

Answer (score 0):

Path in your directory and pubsec is:
`assets/images/b.jpg`

But in your code its:
`assets/Images/b.jpg`

change path in code to:
`assets/images/b.jpg`

Comment: you know how can i set Radius.circular for image ?